# How to get the model name from the table name in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp

In one of my projects, I have a function :

```
public function select($table){
        $model=Inflector::singularize($table);
        $result=$this->$model->find('all'));
        ...........
        ...........
}
```

Here, I tried to get the `Model` name from the given "table name"($table), and used `find` function of that model to select all data from that table. But that didn't work.

So, what should I do here ? Can anybody please help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Add some code to your question. And explain a bit more as you did in comment.

Comment: You have to camelize too... and of course this will only work in case you are following the CakePHP naming conventions for models and tables. ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: Yeah, I'll always mention the version :) . And, I am following the naming conventions here, but still its not working. And, what should I camelize ? @ndm

Comment: Is this code inside of some controller? I don't understand what are you trying to do at all. You can't call model find method like that, since `Inflector::singularize()` returns string.

Comment: Yes, this code is inside a controller, and may be that's it didn't work for me :( . But, at last I got my solution from Arkaprava's trick :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my trick. create table name as per model name, or using substr() or strstr() you can extract table prefix, then you can use your model ,

```
$tableName="myprefix_posts";
$dynamicModelName=strstr($tableName,"myprefix_");
 $this->loadmodel($dynamicModelName);

if( $this->$dynamicModelName->save($this->data)){
// your code
}
```

Comment: I solved my problem ! I just had to use "loadmodel()" function. So, your trick is too close to my solution ! I just didn't understand your "strstr()" stuff, why didn't you just use "$this->loadmodel($tableName)" ? Well, that's ok. And, thanks a lot :) . @Arkaprava

Comment: as i always maintain a table prefix, that's why i'hv used strstr to extract model name from table name. Anyway, hope my contribution helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Inflector class for the table name to be singularized. Example:

```
$dynamicModel = Inflector::singularize($table);
```

When you want to use the model via `$this->Model` you have to load it first.

```
$this->loadmodel($dynamicModel);
```

Comment: Well, I think I should've explained my problem a little more. I am using this : $this->Model->find('all'), where I have to replace "Model" by any model dynamically. And I have to get that model from the given table name.

Answer (score 0):

Just a friendly warning: Try not to use words that might be keywords in PHP or MySQL as variable or function names like you do in the function above (select). You or any other developers might get confused at later stages of development. There is probably no harm, I just don't recommend it.

Enjoy

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, I'll keep it in mind :) @heinkasner